# Nginx location regex not working for sub pages

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have two react applications, one at '/home/user/www' and one at '/home/user/builds/checkout'. I want any url starting with '/checkout' eg. '/checkout/complete', '/checkout/error' to use that application. I have the below setup in my Nginx config file:

```
    root /home/user/www;
    index index.html index.htm;        
    location / {
      if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
      }
    }         

    location ~ ^/checkout?(.*)$ {
            allow all;
            root /home/user/builds;
     if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
      }
            try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
     }

    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

going to the url '/checkout' is working correctly but any other url begining with '/checkout' like '/checkout/complete' and 'checkout/error' are just returning a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks too complicated. Can you try this one?

```
root /home/user/www;
index index.html index.htm;        
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}         

location /checkout/ {
    root /home/user/builds;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /checkout/index.html;
}
```

If the `/checkout` URI won't redirect you to `/checkout/`, add this:

```
location = /checkout {
    return 301 /checkout/;
}
```

Comment: This is working to point all the '/checkout' pages to the application, but now all the included .css and .js files (stored in '/home/user/builds/checkout') are failing with 404.

Comment: If the app requests its assets without the `/checkout` URI prefix, it should be fixed at the app level.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834555/use-nginx-to-reverse-proxy-locally-running-react-app#comment125224985_70834555) comment.

Comment: The app is actually requesting the assets with the /checkout URI as I set it in the Router basename

Comment: That's really strange. When a request let's say for `/checkout/css/style.css` is made, this file should be searched as `/home/user/builds/checkout/css/style.css`. Is it right? Any other locations in your server block that could intercept the request?

Comment: Your `location ~ ^.+\..+$ { ... }` being a regex matching location have a greater priority than the prefix locations so it will intercept any request for any asset using your global root `/home/user/www`. I don't understand why are you put it into your config at all. Remove it and everything should work as expected.